# I want to remove the http:// that is added automaticly on the user profile adress

Tags: user-registration

I am using this field for something else and I don't want http:// to be added infront when it is updated, how can this issue be solved ?

custome theme based on twentyeleven, wp v3.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Consider adding a custom field instead of changing the default fields.

Answer (score 1):

That's baked into core, and would be difficult to filter out. You're better off adding a new field specific for what your goal is. It'll get stored as a text field, and can be used however you please. An example:

```
function ath_cleanup_profile_fields( $contactmethods ) {

$contactmethods['my_new_profile']   = 'Business Name'; 

    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','ath_cleanup_profile_fields',10,1);
```

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detail how and where to insert that, I am just html/css and designer, php is not my strong side but they want me to do some things in the theme and I used some work arounds :)

Comment: that goes in your themes functions file. you grab it using the_author_meta function

Comment: btw i could just edit the core if you tell me how/where if it is easier

Comment: editing core is never the answer, since it'll be wiped out on updates. what exactly are you trying to accomplish, from start to finish? I can probably give you better advice if I know the goal.

Comment: What I needed is a custom registration / login page for users, so I used a plugin so I can customize the looks and names on forms of the registration form, but since I don't know php I was not able to change some things like I use the web adress field for text field but it auto adds http:// infront of the text that is entered. Basicly I got what I need, maybe I would need to change the input boxes from text to textarea too but the more important part is I need the http:// auto adding to be removed for now, thanks for your time helping out by the way

Comment: the URL field is going to add that HTTP into it regardless, so setting your own field is the way to go. The code below will add a custom field to the user profile. How / where do you need it displayed?

`function ath_cleanup_profile_fields( $contactmethods ) {

$contactmethods['my_new_profile_field']   = 'My New Profile Field Name; 

    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','ath_cleanup_profile_fields',10,1);
`

Comment: I need this to appear in the admin part when you check someone's profile I also need it on my custom page to update your profile.

Comment: that's beyond what I've set up. if you aren't capable of doing it, u suggest hiring someone who is.